# Can't create nested list because list.Clear doesn't seem to work as I want

Tags: c#, foreach, nested-lists

I try to load txt file that consists of 200 rows each of different length into nested list so that every sublist inside main list will be equal to row, so there will be 200 sublists.

```
class MainClass
{
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            List<List<int>> arrayList = new List<List<int>>();
            List<int> tmp = new List <int> ();
            string[] file = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\file.txt");

            foreach (string line in  file) {
                string[] linef = line.Split (new char[] { ' ', '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                tmp.Clear ();

                for (int n = 0; n < linef.Length; n++) {
                    tmp.Add (int.Parse (linef [n]));
                }

                arrayList.Add (tmp);
            }
```

But `arrayList` seams to contain only last row - whenever i try to get some number, for a example `arrayList[78][5]`, it gives me 5th number from 200th row no matter what the first index is - 78 or other. I think there is issue with `tmp.Clear` but i cant figure out how to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tmp.Clear()` makes your list empty, that is all. The main list contains only 200 references to your tmp list.
You have to call

```
tmp = new List<int>();
```

instead of

```
tmp.Clear();
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are re-adding the same `List<int> tmp` many times to `arrayList`, so that at the end

```
 bool areSame = object.ReferenceEquals(arrayList[0], arrayList[1]); // true
```

You have **one** `List<int>` with `n` references to it (one for each "row" of `arrayList`)

Change it to:

```
 foreach (string line in  file) {
     List<int> tmp = new List <int> ();
     // No Clear necessary
```